# Easiest way to merge these arrays vertically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have these arras

```
names = ["Will","Bob","John","Ben"]
ages = [45,49,32,49]
postcodes = [9320,3991,1234,2993]
```

Whats the most efficient way to stack them so they appear as

```
people = [["Will",45,9320],["Bob",49,3991],["John",32,1234],["Ben",49,2993]]
```

Does ruby have a function to merge these vertically? (by index) nice and simple without all those nasty loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
people = names.zip(ages, postcodes)

=> [["Will", 45, 9320], ["Bob", 49, 3991], ["John", 32, 1234], ["Ben", 49, 2993]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
people = names.zip ages, postcodes
```